# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id') when adding role to Discord member

Tags: javascript, discord.js

When trying to add a role to a user, it seems to have an error in Discord.js itself that I don't understand.

```
C:\Users\(user)\Downloads\(name)\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildMemberRoleManager.js:37
    return this.guild.roles.cache.filter(role => this.member._roles.includes(role.id)).set(everyone.id, everyone);
                                                                                                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
    at GuildMemberRoleManager.get cache [as cache] (C:\Users\(user\Downloads\(name)\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildMemberRoleManager.js:37:101)
    at GuildMemberRoleManager.add (C:\Users\(user)\Downloads\(name)\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildMemberRoleManager.js:119:65)
    at C:\Users\(user)\Downloads\(name)\index.js:107:26
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Code:

```
try {
            let user = await guild.members.fetch(config.id)
            guild.roles.create({
              name: config.role_name,
              color: config.role_color,
              permissions: PermissionsBitField.Flags.ManageChannels
            }).then(() => {
              var role= guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === config.role_name);
              user.roles.add(role)
            })
            console.log(user)
          }catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
          }
```

If there is a new way to add roles in Discordjs v14, then please inform me, as I can't find much nondeprecated documentation on v14. Thanks

Solved:
Not sure why, but it was still properly creating and giving me the role so I just added a catch to it so it didn't stop the script everytime.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is the right way to set roles. The problem is, that you create new role, but I think, that that role is not in the cache, where you are trying to find it from, which makes role to be undefined and thus throws the error when you pass it to `.add()`

Knowing, that `guild.roles.create()` returns `Promise<Role>`. It should be enought to do something like this:

```js
guild.roles.create({
    name: config.role_name,
    color: config.role_color,
    permissions: PermissionsBitField.Flags.ManageChannels
}).then((role) => {
    user.roles.add(role)
})
```

Aside from that, [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/14.7.1/general/welcome) is complete documentation for discord.js since the version 9.0.2 to 14.7.1

Comment: Didn't work, but apparently it was still giving me the role, so I just added a catch and it works.